# mobx observable field not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am new to mobx so forgive me for a likely basic question. Here's what I have:

```
@observable myInfo;

...

@observer
class Klass {

    @computed get myInfo() {
        if (cond1 && cond2) {
            return `${data1} ${data2}`;
        }

        return '';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.myInfo}
                <MyComponent info={someFunction(myInfo)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

For some reason, `{this.myInfo}` is getting updated just fine, but when I pass `myInfo` to `someFunction` which is then a prop to `MyComponent`, that `myInfo` doesn't get updated. Basically, the uses of `myInfo` contain different values.

I don't totally understand mobx, so an explanation of what's going wrong would be awesome :)

Comment: Is MyComponent decorated with @observer?

Comment: Does passing this.myInfo to MyComponent solve your problem?  <MyComponent info={someFunction(this.myInfo)} />